# GPS coordinations for each kilometer

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, gps, openstreetmap

I'll find a route between two places, for example using google maps. I'd like to divide the route to kilometers (two following places will be at a distance of 1 km), and get GPS coordinations of these places. This is because then I'll be able to get exacly the coordinations of, for example, 5th kilometer on the route. Could you please advice me how to achieve it?

Comment: [markers every 2 km on a polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html).  You can get a polyline from the directions service.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you. That's what I need. If you place it as regular answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @geocodezip wich service will give you the polyline? .

Comment: The [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) - [example with 2 markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely nontrivial. Is say your best bet is to find an algorithm to load the bearing between two points, then one to load a coordinate given a start point, distance, and bearing. This could give you it, but only if the data contained only straight lines. Since I assume the Google Maps API only gives you the turns the user has to make, this approach will be inaccurate when there are bends in roads. You'd need GIS data for roads and what will undoubtedly turn into a complicated algorithm to find something like this. It's definitely doable, but that's l how I'd start. Look into the Census TIGER road data, it should help.

Unless, of course, I'm wrong and the API does actually give enough points to cleanly map it, in which case those functions should be easy to find and implement.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if you have the polyline as a sequence of lat/lon (or other) coordinates, wherever you get that from.

Then you start at the beginning an iterate through the lines (point[i], point[i+1]).
THis distance you calculate with standard API.
while itersting you sum up the distance.
Once you exceed the 1000m, you know that the splitting point (the 1000m marker) is at line segment [i,i+1].
To calculate the exact position where on the line that is, you take the total summed meters from previous segment, and the value of this segment and do a linear interpolation.

The working code is a bit complexer: there can be multiple markes within one segement.

But first find out where you get the polyline from, whitou that it will not work.